# Unresponsive script ckeditor.js error on 1 page drupal 6 site

Tags: ckeditor, drupal-6

I'm working on an older drupal 6 site. The ckeditor on a specific page freezes everything and the browser throws an unresponsive script error. On other pages ckeditor is working fine. What could cause the unresponsive script error on just 1 page?

Comment: Please include the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Actually I fixed it, there was some bad html in the content area, an a tag with 3 double quotes, and this was totally killing it. Thanks!